# How to display images on Magento secure checkout

Tags: image, magento, ssl

I have a website running Magento and just installed SSL Certificate and images get 404 error not found now. All settings in administration under web are set correctly for SSL. The images come from https:// but don't display.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: One of the most common reasons for this is having hotlink protection enabled on your site.  Have you tried to disable it?

Comment: Yes, you got it, in my .htaccess. Thanks